# Java Out of memory EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)

Tags: java

I have a java application, it had been running for 1 month.
It suddenly crashes with this error message. I use nssm to create windows service for my application.

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6ecf4803, pid=4484, tid=1040
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x154803]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# D:\dir\hs_err_pid4484.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

This is hs_err_pid4484.log (not Full Log)

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6ecf4803, pid=4484, tid=1040
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_79-b15) (build 1.7.0_79-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (24.79-b02 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0x154803]
#
# Failed to write core dump. Call to MiniDumpWriteDump() failed
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x2be27800):  JavaThread "hz.10.252.223.144.cached.thread-7" [_thread_in_vm, id=1040, stack(0x2d0b0000,0x2d100000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x2d0f77f4

Registers:
EAX=0x00006000, EBX=0x2c4cb7e4, ECX=0x2d0f77f4, EDX=0x2d0b9078
ESP=0x2d0fd800, EBP=0x2d0fd864, ESI=0x00000007, EDI=0x2d0fd7f4
EIP=0x6ecf4803, EFLAGS=0x00010202

Top of Stack: (sp=0x2d0fd800)
0x2d0fd800:   2c4cb7e8 2be27800 6ecf4f93 2be27800
0x2d0fd810:   2b3d0748 2d0fd9cc 00000000 00000000
0x2d0fd820:   00000000 07100146 0008fe12 00000060
0x2d0fd830:   010101ec 00e50358 00000000 2be27930
0x2d0fd840:   6ed1635d 00000000 2c39d2e8 00e50048
0x2d0fd850:   00e50170 2d0fd9d4 0000000a 3ab09782
0x2d0fd860:   2c4cb7e4 2d0fd8ac 6edc479e 2d0fd9cc
0x2d0fd870:   010fd8d4 2d0fd940 01625280 1fe13366 

Instructions: (pc=0x6ecf4803)
0x6ecf47e3:   a9 00 0d 00 be 01 00 00 00 8b f8 39 35 80 65 0a
0x6ecf47f3:   6f 7c 1b e8 15 54 06 00 0f af c6 8b cf 2b c8 46
0x6ecf4803:   c7 01 00 00 00 00 3b 35 80 65 0a 6f 7e e5 5f 5e
0x6ecf4813:   c3 cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc cc 55 8b ec 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00006000 is an unknown value
EBX=0x2c4cb7e4 is an unknown value
ECX=0x2d0f77f4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2be27800
EDX=0x2d0b9078 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2be27800
ESP=0x2d0fd800 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2be27800
EBP=0x2d0fd864 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2be27800
ESI=0x00000007 is an unknown value
EDI=0x2d0fd7f4 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x2be27800


Stack: [0x2d0b0000,0x2d100000],  sp=0x2d0fd800,  free space=310k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0x154803]
V  [jvm.dll+0x22479e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x15505d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd7152]
V  [jvm.dll+0xd8f7f]
C  [instrument.dll+0x2e9e]
C  [instrument.dll+0x19c1]
V  [jvm.dll+0x118d2e]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11c824]
V  [jvm.dll+0x39640]
V  [jvm.dll+0x4c4e7]
V  [jvm.dll+0x10381f]
V  [jvm.dll+0x103a6b]
C  [java.dll+0x166a]
C  [zip.dll+0x1b28]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/ProtectionDomain;)Ljava/lang/Class;+30
j  java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BIILjava/security/CodeSource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+12
j  java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;Lsun/misc/Resource;)Ljava/lang/Class;+220
J 546 C2 java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run()Ljava/lang/Object; (5 bytes) @ 0x0178859c [0x01788080+0x51c]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
J 966  java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Ljava/security/PrivilegedExceptionAction;Ljava/security/AccessControlContext;)Ljava/lang/Object; (0 bytes) @ 0x016a3f07 [0x016a3ea0+0x67]
J 544 C2 java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (29 bytes) @ 0x016d5780 [0x016d5720+0x60]
J 1079 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;Z)Ljava/lang/Class; (122 bytes) @ 0x01834128 [0x01833800+0x928]
J 1200 C2 java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class; (82 bytes) @ 0x0190c148 [0x0190c0a0+0xa8]
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  com.hazelcast.instance.OutOfMemoryErrorDispatcher$DefaultOutOfMemoryHandler.onOutOfMemory(Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;[Lcom/hazelcast/core/HazelcastInstance;)V+32
j  com.hazelcast.instance.OutOfMemoryErrorDispatcher.onOutOfMemory(Ljava/lang/OutOfMemoryError;)V+46
j  com.hazelcast.util.executor.PoolExecutorThreadFactory$ManagedThread.run()V+33
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
```

The application can be restarted, but I have to investigate the root cause of this problem.

Thanks.

Comment: You might check the event log. If possible, you could run something like [memtest86](http://www.memtest86.com/) on the machine.